# Add an echo after a grep search

Tags: linux, bash, grep, echo, gnome-terminal

Is there a way to add an echo after a grep command?

For example if I run this:

```
grep -R $id && echo appearances in database
```

The output is

```
listofids.txt:226526658 201
appearances in database
```

Is there a way to get it to display as such:

```
listofids.txt:226526658 201 appearances in database
```

I have tried a few ideas that came to mind but nothing worked, for example :

```
echo "" grep -R $id "appearances in database"
```

I knew it wouldn't work but I thought it was worth a shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do:

```
echo "$(grep -R $id) appearances in database"
```